# Userscript - multiple vs single script file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, tampermonkey, userscripts

Technically speaking, are there any difference in performance when having multiple userscripts running on the same page vs combining them in a single script?
Assuming functionally the same and script management is not an issue, is one preferred than the other?

Comment: Code splitting per se should be negligible. Merging is beneficial if there's a lot of shared functionality e.g. every script uses a MutationObserver for the same target/config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding JavaScript running in a webpage, as mentioned by wOxxOm, unless there are duplicate processes, it does not matter if there are in one snippet (*e.g. segment or file*) or multiple snippets.

However, loading (*e.g. by `import()`*) or injection (*e.g. by userscript managers*) is a different matter, as each file takes resources to load/inject (*some of which are asynchronous*).

Although modern computers and JavaScript engines are very efficient and can perform 1000s of operations in mere milliseconds, loading/injection is worth considering.